# Postgres SQL: Do paging and total count rows in a union set.

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following sql at the begnging.

```
select col1, col2 from table1
union
select col1, col2 from table2
```

Now I want to able to do a count the total number of rows in the union set from above, and order by col2. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
with a as (
select col1, col2 from table1
union
select col1, col2 from table2 
)
select *,count(1) over()
from a
order by col2
;
```